# Pass block to module included hook

Tags: ruby

I want to include a module passing also a configuration block.

Right now I have something like this

```
class Check
  include Zabase::ObjectPrinter 
  pp_values :title 
end
```

Because I do not want to pollute the namespace of the `Check` class, I want to use a DSL block like this:

```
class Check
  include Zabase::ObjectPrinter do
     pp_values :title 
  end

  # calling pp_values here should fail
end
```

Is it possible to implement this? I've seen that the `self.included` does not receive the block.

Answer (score 3):

The common way to achieve this would be:

```
module Zabase::ObjectPrinter

  # ...

  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def zabase_configure &block
      instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
    end
  end 
end
```

and then

```
class Check
  include Zabase::ObjectPrinter

  zabase_configure do
    ...
  end
end
```